# How to remove folders from TableView when working with the file system

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a TableView application that displays the contents of the Documents directory. I put all the elements of local directory to array "content" and load TableView from this array. But I want to see in TableView only files (.mp3) but not subfolders. I want subfolders don't even been added to the array "content". How can I do it? I try to use .isDirectory property in func cellFoRowAt and delete subfolders from array "content". But application crashes when I try to delete some row, it happens because invalid number of rows in section.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var currentDirectory: String?
    var content: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reloadData()
    }
    
    private func reloadData(needsReload: Bool = true) {
        
        if currentDirectory == nil {
            currentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        }
        do {
            content = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: currentDirectory! )
        } catch {
            content = []
        }
        if needsReload {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    private func isDirectory(atPath: String) -> Bool? {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: atPath)
        
        if let object = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]) {
            if object.isDirectory! {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return content.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row]
        if let directory = isDirectory(atPath: fullPath) {
            if directory {
                content.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "File"
            }
        }
        ...
        return cell
    }
    
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty bad approach. Never delete a data source item in `cellForRowAt`.

Rather than reading the file names read the URLs and filter the data by the path extension. You can display the name easily with `lastPathComponent`

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    lazy var currentDirectory : URL = {
        return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    }()
    
    var content: [URL] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reloadData()
    }
    
    private func reloadData(needsReload: Bool = true) {
        do {
            let allURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: currentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
            content = allURLs.filter{$0.pathExtension == "mp3"}
        } catch {
            content = []
        }
        if needsReload {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return content.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = content[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
        
        // ...
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: **contentsOfDirectory**  Options for the enumeration. Because this method performs only shallow enumerations, options that prevent descending into subdirectories or packages are not allowed; the only supported option is skipsHiddenFiles. btw regarding **pathExtension** This property contains the path extension, unescaped using the replacingPercentEscapes(using:) method. For example, in the URL file:///path/to/file.txt, the path extension is txt. So `filter{$0.pathExtension == "mp3"}`